# Why is this query taking so long to execute in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I want to reduce the execution time. Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    StoreID,
    ItemLookupCode,
    sum(TotalQuantity) TotalQuantity,
    sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
    sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JCF_ItemDailySalesParent]
WHERE
    time >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 102) AND
    time <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-12-31 00:00:00', 102)
GROUP BY 
    ItemLookupCode, StoreID
```

It's taking **3 min 33 sec** to execute this query. Total number of records in that table is **8 Million**. The total number of rows records retrieved from the database is **87,000**

I created index for all the columns.

**Table Definition**

```
[StoreID]             [nchar](150)      NOT NULL,
[ItemLookupCode]      [nvarchar](25)    NULL,
[ExtendedDescription] [varchar](3000)   NULL,
[DepartmentID]        [int]             NULL,
[DepartmentName]      [nvarchar](30)    NULL,
[CategoryID]          [int]             NULL,
[CategoryName]        [nvarchar](30)    NULL,
[SupplierID]          [int]             NULL,
[SupplierCode]        [nvarchar](17)    NULL,
[SupplierName]        [nvarchar](30)    NULL,
[Time]                [datetime]        NOT NULL,
[TotalQuantity]       [float]           NULL,
[ExtendedPrice]       [float]           NULL,
[ExtendedCost]        [float]           NULL`
```

**Index Definition**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JCF_AllColumns] ON [dbo].[JCF_ItemDailySalesParent]
(
[Time]                ASC,
[ItemLookupCode]      ASC,
[StoreID]             ASC,
[ExtendedDescription] ASC,
[DepartmentID]        ASC,
[DepartmentName]      ASC,
[CategoryID]          ASC,
[CategoryName]        ASC,
[SupplierID]          ASC,
[SupplierCode]        ASC,
[SupplierName]        ASC,
[TotalQuantity]       ASC,
[ExtendedPrice]       ASC,
[ExtendedCost]        ASC
)
```

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: why negative marks?

Comment: It depends on several things. your hardware, your indexing method, etc. your question has low clue to find the best solution.

Comment: @NimaRostami Did you give the negative marks?

Comment: Can you please show the **table structure** of the table involved, and provide the **exact definition** of how you created those indexes? Also: which **version** of SQL Server are you using? 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 ??

Comment: @mohamedfaisal Yes I Did. but I removed it.

Comment: @marc_s can you check now?

Comment: What kind of **clustering key** do you have on your table?

Comment: Can you provide examples of your longest length StoreIDs?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot to remove the ASC.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan ?  The index you created is large.  You could have only used the Time,ItemLookUpCode and StoreID and placed the rest in the "Include" section.  That would make the index much more efficient.  Also, check in the execution plan. Perhaps because of the size, the index isn't being used at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created the datatype, you can avoid nchar type. You are storing only numbers on **StoreID**. It's just only four digit.

> `[StoreID]             [nchar](150)      NOT NULL`
>
> Change the datatype into varchar(10). **nchar is unicode format.** It will make the size double. As well as you put the **nchar size is 150**. This will create a memory for all the charecters even though you don't use more than 4 char.
>
> Due to the size of nchar(150) It will create **multiple pages on Index(unwanted b-tree pages)**

So change into following constraint

> `[StoreID]             [varchar](10)      NOT NULL`
>
> And create the following index
>
> `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JCF_AllColumns] ON [dbo].[JCF_ItemDailySalesParent]
>       (
>       [Time]                ASC,
>       [TotalQuantity]       ASC,
>       [ExtendedPrice]       ASC,
>       [ExtendedCost]        ASC
>       )
>       INCLUDE(
>       [ItemLookupCode]  ,
>       [StoreID]
>
>   )`

Comment: How come your username is exactly the same as that of the questioner? Just coincidence or are you the same person?

Comment: How do you know StoreID is 4 characters?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to index on every column, try this index:

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JCF_AllColumns] ON [dbo].[JCF_ItemDailySalesParent]
    (
    [Time]                ASC,
    [TotalQuantity]       ASC,
    [ExtendedPrice]       ASC,
    [ExtendedCost]        ASC
    )
    INCLUDE(
    [ItemLookupCode]  ,
    [StoreID]             
)
```

In your WHERE clause you don't need the CONVERT function, this should work.

```
SELECT 
    StoreID,
    ItemLookupCode,
    sum(TotalQuantity) TotalQuantity,
    sum(ExtendedPrice) ExtendedPrice,
    sum(ExtendedCost) ExtendedCost
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[JCF_ItemDailySalesParent]
WHERE
    time >= '20150101' AND
    time <= '20151231'
GROUP BY 
    ItemLookupCode, StoreID
```

Does the [StoreID] column have to be NCHAR? Unless the Store IDs are 150 characters long you should change the column to NVARCHAR, then rebuild you indexes.

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ASC'` on this line `INCLUDE(
[ItemLookupCode]      ASC, // error
[StoreID]             ASC
)`

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JCF_foo] ON [dbo].[JCF_ItemDailySalesParent] (
    [Time],
    [StoreID],
    [ItemLookupCode]
) INCLUDE (
    [TotalQuantity],
    [ExtendedPrice],
    [ExtendedCost]
)
```

This should enable the optimizer to do use an index-only query.

Also try this, which may enable grouping on the fly:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [JCF_foo] ON [dbo].[JCF_ItemDailySalesParent] (
    [StoreID],
    [ItemLookupCode],
    [Time]
) INCLUDE (
    [TotalQuantity],
    [ExtendedPrice],
    [ExtendedCost]
)
```

Comment: Up vote from me, I think we had our time wasted with this question.